# React not updating className when passing a function reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'm making a small example in React. One of the issues I came across is, when I pass a function reference to a `onClick` event handler and when that event is executed, react is not updating a class on the component, that is, it is not executing another function defined in the component.

Here's a snippet of code where the issue is. The entire code snippet can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/h6k4um9o/

```
const Numbers = (props) => {
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    props.selectNumber(event.target.innerText)
  }
  const numberClassName = (number) => {
    if(props.selectedNumbers.indexOf(number) >= 0) {
      return 'selected';
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="card text-center">
      <div>
        {Numbers.list.map((number, index) =>
        <span key={index} className={numberClassName(number)} 
              onClick={handleClick}>{number}</span>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above code when we pass `handleClick` reference to the `onClick` event it will not apply the class added by `numberClassName`. However, the issue is resolved when using an inline function.

`onClick={() => props.selectNumber(number)}>{number}</span>`

Any idea about this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `handleClick` function expects a number and you are passing a string. It should work if you change it to

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    props.selectNumber(Number(event.target.innerText))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `event.target.innerText` is a string and you are using `indexOf` to return the number class name.

Accorgind to the Mozilla Documentation about [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict
>   equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator).

That means that it checks for type and equality.

For example:

```js
console.log("0" == 0); // true
console.log("0" === 0); //false
```

So you just need to do this:

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
  props.selectNumber(parseInt(event.target.innerText));
}
```

and your code will work just fine without the inline function.

Answer (score 1):

SelectNumber expects a number type but you are passing a string type. event.target.innerText returns string.

Just convert the string using Number Constructor.

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
        props.selectNumber(Number(event.target.innerText));
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the way you are using your handler and variable format that is expected. Here is the working code with passing a function reference:

```
const Numbers = (props) => {


  const handleClick = (event) => {
    props.selectNumber(parseInt(event.target.innerText))
  }

  const numberClassName = (number) => {
    if(props.selectedNumbers.indexOf(number) >= 0) {
      return 'selected';
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="card text-center">
      <div>
        {Numbers.list.map((number, index) =>
        <span key={index} className={numberClassName(number)} 
              onClick={handleClick}>{number}</span>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a [solution fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6k4um9o/1/)